# Custom Pushpin wp7

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone

I want to create a user control which inherit from Pushpin but it didn't work. Secondly i wanted create new User Control with GeoCoordinate Location like in Pushpin, but when i tried to add it to my Map it didn't occur in good places.
So here is my question:

How to create Pushpin with a list of other items or something.I have to extend Pushpin class.

Comment: How did you try this? What happened when "it didn't work"?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a UserControl to customize the layout of a Pushpin. Instead you should use a Style.

Microsoft wrote a nice guide about how to use Bing Maps, and create custom styled pushpins, you can [read it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447).

[Pushpins in many colours http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447.9cb28f2d-692e-427e-a778-964990afe6bb(en-us).png](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266447.9cb28f2d-692e-427e-a778-964990afe6bb(en-us).png)

Comment: Most people are to lazy to read links, without a **really** good reason for doing so :p